# How to overcome problem with type erasure for visitor implementation

Tags: java, generics, visitor-pattern, type-erasure

I am starting to work with Java after some projects in C# and C++.

I wanted to design visitor interfaces like this:

```
public interface ActionVisitor<A> {
    void visitAction(A action);    
}

public interface MySmallActionVisitor 
extends ActionVisitor<ActionA>,
    ActionVisitor<ActionB>
{

}

public interface MyFullActionVisitor 
extends ActionVisitor<ActionA>,
    ActionVisitor<ActionB>,ActionVisitor<ActionC>,ActionVisitor<ActionD> //....
{

}
```

Of course this doesn't work because of type erasure. (The reason why I want something like this is that I will have different Visitor interfaces for different groups of Actions that can be visited.)

The only solution that comes to my mind is to declare interfaces

```
public interface ActionAVisitor {
        void visitAction(ActionA action);    
    }
public interface ActionBVisitor {
        void visitAction(ActionB action);    
    }
//...
```

and then

```
public interface MySmallActionVisitor 
extends ActionAVisitor, ActionBVisitor
{

}
```

This would work, but I wouldn't like the declaration of all the ActionXVisitor-Interfaces which is stupid repetition and lots of files...

Do you have any ideas how to do this better?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work with a large and complex library in Java which extensively uses the Visitor Pattern in a very clean and neat way. In particular, I came across with the same problem of type erasure and it is solved now.

If you have a chance, please have a look at [an article I've written about this](http://rgomes-info.blogspot.com/2013/01/a-better-implementation-of-visitor.html).

It's a long article, which explains in detail what the Visitor pattern is about conceptually and, in last part of the article, it is discussed a real life example which involves polymorphism and type erasure.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would use a single unparameterized visitor interface, then inside the visitor method do the dispatch based on type.

Comment: you mean using "instanceof"? That's what the visitor pattern wants to avoid. Furthermore, I would have to write these if blocks in every visitor (MySmallVisitor, MyFullVisitor and others).

Comment: yes, i meant instanceof. attempting to avoid it, will likely lead to far more code in the end.

Comment: if there's really no way to overcome the problem I described I'd rather have more code than instanceof code... Poor language :-(

Answer (score -2):

There's no way to be able to avoid instanceof of inside the method. But you can make it more graceful:

```
public interface MarkerInterface{}

public interface ActionVisitor<T extends MarkerInterface> {
void visitAction(T action);}

public class A implements MarkerInterface{}

public class B implements MarkerInterface{}

public class MySmallActionVisitor implements ActionVisitor<MarkerInterface>{

@Override
public void visitAction(MarkerInterface action) {
    if(action instanceof A){

    }
    else if(action instanceof B){

    }
}
```

}

Comment: sorry, have you ever heard of the visitor pattern? Of course it is possible to avoid it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example